# Buttons with fixed dimensions inside Jtoolbar

Tags: java, button, toolbar

Ideally I would have 2 columns of buttons in my toolbar, but have a fixed dimension of say (30,30). I currently have a grid layout that works good for the layout, but the buttons strech to fit and I want the buttons to stay square. What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
public SpecToolbar(SpecController con) {
            super(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2)); 
            setFloatable(false);    

            ButtonGroup g = new ButtonGroup();

            add(new SelectorButton(con, g));
            add(new InfoButton(con));
            add(new ZoomInButton(con, g));
            add(new ZoomOutButton(con, g));
            add(new CrossButton(con, g));
            add(new GridButton(con));
            add(new BaselineUpButton(con));
            add(new BaselineDownButton(con));
            add(new PeakUpButton(con));
            add(new PeakDownButton(con));
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: Make the container for the grid a fixed size so the buttons end up 30x30 when expanded inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer would be to use different layout. If you want to align your buttons horizontally just use simple `FlowLayout`. If you want to align them vertically use [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html), [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), or [MiGLayout.](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/framework/miglayout-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

> but the buttons strech to fit

What does that mean? Since you have 2 columns and 5 rows I'm guessing your are adding the toolbar to the WEST of a BorderLayout so the buttons height will stretch?

You can solve your problems by nesting layouts. For example:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 2) );
buttonPanel.add(...);
JPanel toolbarPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
toolbarPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(toolBarPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Now all your buttons will be the same size. Any extra height will go below the buttons so they don't get stretched vertically.